# Can we show user location in offline in MKMapview

Tags: gps, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, cllocation

Can we get current user location "That blue ball which is animating" when our device is offline.when i tried to get current user location and log it i'm getting 0.00000 for both longitude and latitude here is the code that i used to get current user location.I'm using ipad mini to test it.I have also added CLLocationManagerDelegate in .h file.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [self getUserLocation];
      self.myMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

 }
-(void)getUserLocation{
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}else{
    NSLog(@"User location Disabled");
}


}

 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
 {
CLLocation *currentGPSLocation = newLocation;

if (currentGPSLocation != nil) {
    currentLocation.latitude = self.myMapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    currentLocation.longitude = self.myMapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude;

    currentLocationWalk.latitude=self.myMapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    currentLocationWalk.longitude=self.myMapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %f,%f", self.myMapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude,self.myMapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    statusLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.myMapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    statusLabel1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.myMapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude];



}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'offline'? No internet connection at all (no wifi and no cellular data connection) or in Airplane mode?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using ARC (I strongly suggest using it, it avoid most of the memory management errors!).
Therefore it might be that "`locationManager`" is a instance variable that is not retained (maybe you did not declare it as a retained property).
In this case, it might have been released already when your code returns to the main run loop, where the autorelease pool is drained.

Comment: I'm not even getting user location ball in offline

Comment: Please ensure that your location manager is NOT released automatically when you return to the event loop, i.e. that your locationManager iVar is retained. Otherwise you won't have an location manager that could give you the user's location.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
```

is not a good idea.

define the locationManager as a property, 
init the locationManager in viewDidLoad(), but remove the autorelease!

and relase the locationManager only when the viewController is unloaded (there where you release the other properties)

Comment: The above code is working perfectly, But im using iPad mini to test it deoesn't have GPS

Comment: It works for luck, when leaving the method, the location manager could be autorrelased, before the callback could be called. And you alocate an instance of loctaion manager evry time you call getLocation() this is not a good idea.